# Visualization of MySQL/PostgreSQL table structure as a graph/UML

Tags: mysql, postgresql, graph

Is there any program, source code or API that will take a MySQL or PostgreSQL schema and
spit out a UML or some other graph visualizing of it?

Answer (score 5):

A useful little protip - Visio is quite widely available within corporate I.T. suites and Visio Pro or higher can be used to reverse engineer and document a database.

Visio professional has a database reverse engineering tool that will read a database schema and create E-R models from it.  Both PostgreSQL and MySQL support ODBC INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables so the ODBC driver for the Visio DB modeller will work with them.  Start by creating a database diagram, and then look for 'Reverse Engineer' under the 'Database' menu.

As a bonus, if the physical DB has missing foreign key constraints you can add them back into the model for documentation purposes.  For a more complex schema you can also create several diagrams showing different subsystems.  I find myself using this to document systems at client sites on a semi-regular basis and it's often the only tool available.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect)? The open source version can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at SchemaSpy. It creates quite nice reports and diagrams:

http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) will do this for MySQL databases.

Comment: Hey, Just wanted to add, I used this one, and it looks nice, however it doesnt auto detect relationships for me since they are in singular-plural fashion (users -> user_id), So I had to do it myself. The last button does this, shortcut is 6